# Concat certain columns to one with no standard number of columns in each loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary:

```
#file1 mentions 2 columns while file2 mentions 3
dict2 = ({'file1' : ['colA', 'colB'],'file2' : ['colY','colS','colX'], etc..})
```

I want to do a concatenation of the mentioned columns in a new column for each file.
This should be automated.

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v)) #reads to a df
    df['new'] = df['first_col'].astype(str) + df['second_col'] etc.. #concatenation
```

How can I make this work every time, independent of the number of columns in each dictionary?

Simply to concatenate all the mentioned columns.

Example:

```
a = {'colA' : [123,124,112,165],'colB' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']}
file1 = pd.DataFrame(data = a)
file1

colA   colB
123    alpha
124    beta
112    gamma
165    delta

b = {'colY' : [123,124,112,165],'colS' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'], 'colX' :[323,326,378,399] }
file2 = pd.DataFrame(data = b)
file2

colY  colS      colX
123   alpha     323
124   beta      326
112   gamma     378
165   delta     399
```

Result:

file1

```
col_all
123 alpha
124 beta
112 gamma
165 delta
```

file2

```
call_all
123 alpha 323
124 beta  326
112 gamma 378
165 delta 399
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need change:

```
df['new'] = df['first_col'].astype(str) + df['second_col']
```

to converting all columns to strings and then `join` them with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1` for processing by rows:

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: The main issue is in the bigger picture.That this has to be in a loop and the first file has two columns and the other 3. How to automate a concatenation that will work on as many columns a file in the loop may have?

Comment: @user51332 - not sure if understand, `df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)` working with all columns, there is not necessary define columns names.

Comment: Sorry then. You suggest to not define columns and it will take them all to one.Thanks

Comment: In some cases I will have to include columns in each file that would have to remain out of this concat process. How to include them in the dict so they will not be affected and just be there too

Comment: @user51332 - do you think processes only columns define in values in dict? Something like `df['new'] = df[v].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)` ?

Comment: if I understood correctly ''process only columns defined in values in dict" is this case we have here.The scenario I suggested before is to define also some columns in values but choose to concat to one column only a few of those because we need the others to be there in the final dataframe too.

Comment: @user51332 - so in loop you define columns for concat? Then use `df['new'] = df[list_of_necessary_columns].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)`

Comment: I don't really get it. Since it is a kind of more precised question do you want to ask a question and notify you here to go check it?Thanks for the answer.

Comment: the question is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151678/choose-which-columns-to-concat-in-a-loop-of-files-with-different-cumber-of-colum

Comment: It caused `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)` at your last line. and did `import sys
... reload(sys)
... sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` which fixed it though everyone says to not use this solution. What is going on? I am using Greek letters if it matters.

Comment: @user51332 - Really hard to answering, I have no idea, sorry :(