# Choose which columns to concat in a loop of files with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary:

```
#file1 mentions 2 columns while file2 mentions 3
dict2 = ({'file1' : ['colA', 'colB'],'file2' : ['colY','colS','colX'], etc..})
```

First of all how to make the dictionary in a way that will separate somehow the values headed to a *one column concatenation* from the columns that are needed to remain in the final dataframe unaffected.

The columns will not have the same names for each file and it is very difficult to automate such customized process. What do you think?

I want to do a concatenation of the mentioned columns in a new column for each file.
This should be automated.

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v)) #reads to a df
    df['new'] = df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)#concatenation
```

How can I make this work every time, independent of the number of columns in each dictionary?

Example:

```
a = {'colA' : [123,124,112,165],'colB' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']}
file1 = pd.DataFrame(data = a)
file1

colA   colB
123    alpha
124    beta
112    gamma
165    delta

b = {'colY' : [123,124,112,165],'colS' :['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'], 'colX' :[323,326,378,399] }
file2 = pd.DataFrame(data = b)
file2

colY  colS      colX 
123   alpha     323
124   beta      326
112   gamma     378
165   delta     399
```

Result:

file1

```
col_all
123 alpha
124 beta
112 gamma
165 delta
```

file2

```
call_all
123 alpha 323
124 beta  326
112 gamma 378
165 delta 399
```

**NOTE**

`file2` for example could have 5 more columns but only 3 should be concatenated to a one column. How to make the initial dict that would define which columns to be concatenated and what to just exist there unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to select columns names for concat, e.g first 3 columns selected by positions:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v)) #reads to a df
    df['new'] = df.iloc[:, :3].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)#concatenation
```

If create list of possible columns names use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v)) #reads to a df
    L = ['colA','colB','colS']
    cols = df.columns.intersection(L)
    df['new'] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)#concatenation
```

Or filtering:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v)) #reads to a df
    L = ['colA','colB','colS']
    mask = df.columns.isin(L)
    df['new'] = df.loc[:, mask].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)#concatenation
```

EDIT:

If want create another data structure with another list of necessary columns names, possible solution is create list of tuples:

```
L = [('file1', ['colA', 'colB'], ['colA','colB']), 
     ('file2', ['colY','colS','colX'], ['colY','colS'])]

for i, j, k in L:
    print (i)
    print (j)
    print (k)

file1
['colA', 'colB']
['colA', 'colB']
file2
['colY', 'colS', 'colX']
['colY', 'colS']
```

So your solution should be rewritten:

```
for i, j, k in L:
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, j)) #reads to a df
    df['new'] = df[k].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)#concatenation
```

Comment: Yes I should make a pattern but that would be standard and some files may have 10 columns where only 5 need to be concatenated.

Comment: that would be great but they don't have common columns. they are different files.

Comment: @user51332 - yes, so how is possible distinguish what columns is necessary concat? What is rule?

Comment: The  only way as I am thinking is to somehow separate them in a previous step like when making the dictionary. I t is a wrong example but it may give you an idea: make a list instead of a dict like this file1 = [1,2,3[123,345,234]] and access through an index the sublist with the columns to be concatenated.

Comment: by the way don't delete the existing code you have written. Your answer is great, it's just the scenario that is too perplexing.

Comment: @user51332 - Sure, no problem. I suggest create list of tuples and change loop, check last edit.

Comment: So `k` contains the columns for concat. In the last line  will the whole df has also the other columns in the end?

Comment: @user51332 - yes, in last line `df[k]` seelct only columns names from list `k` - it is `['colA', 'colB']` and `['colY', 'colS']` for `L = [('file1', ['colA', 'colB'], ['colA','colB']), 
     ('file2', ['colY','colS','colX'], ['colY','colS'])]
`